# Cannot change server connection collation in phpmyadmin on local WAMP server

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Please help here as I could not change the server connection collation from utfmb4_general_ci to utf_general_ci, it keeps on refreshing back to utfmb4 no matter what I select. If I select utf_unicode_ci, it changed to utfmb4_unicode_ci.

It is quite frustrating.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your local WAMP server you can first change mysql.ini to change the default character set and collation

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

That will allow you to use the desired charset without sending
'set NAMES'
and
'set CHARSET'
with each connection to DB so it will speed up your application.

I would also suggest that you use the MySQL Workbench instead of phpmyadmin: https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ or another tool such as Heidi or Toad for managing your server.

Comment: Thanks David, However, I tried to put the code into the my.ini, and also tried workbench, but both doesnt work as when I go to the phpmysql, the utf8mb4 is stilled preset even I choose utf8. Would you mind if you can help me further on such issue?

Comment: OK post up your mysql.ini for us. Personally I find XAMPP much better than WAMP, but both are still OK. It is just the XAMPP control panel is so much better. Having edited the mysql.ini, did you resstart the server?

Comment: public function postConnect($link, $is_controluser = false) I found this function in Databaseinterface.class.php, and I changed the following and it works. What do you think? Is this an appropriate method?

Comment: // Skip charsets for Drizzle
        if (!PMA_DRIZZLE) {
            if (PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION >  50503) {
                $default_charset = 'utf8';
                $default_collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
            } else {
                $default_charset = 'utf8';
                $default_collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
            }

Comment: If it works then OK. Still better to set the server default. I have no experience with Drizzle so I can not comment on the best method.

Comment: OK. However, I have done what you told. But still not working. What do you think?

Comment: Just tried install wordpress, and the database collation has set to utf8mb4...damn

Comment: For xampp I think there are too many errors when running on my PC. It seems xampp is a bit too advanced for me.

Comment: Is okay. I upgraded the hosting, no need to edit settings locally.